# How This command not run on quasar project "ENV_FILE=dev quasar build"?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a quasar project, I want to pass via cmd the name of the envirnomets variable for example: ENV_FILE=dev quasar build, for dev envirnonment, ENV_FILE=stg quasar build, for staging
and: ENV_FILE=prd quasar build, for production

I have created the files .env.dev, .env.prd, .env.stg
now in the quasar.config.js, I have something like this:

```
module.exports = configure(function(ctx) {
    require('dotenv').config();
    const env = require('dotenv').config({
        path: `.env.${process.env.ENV_FILE.toLowerCase()}`
    }).parsed;
    return {
        env: {
            ...env
        }
    }
    )
}
```

The problem is process.env.ENV_FILE undefined? How can I get the value passed via cmd e.g: ENV_FILE=dev quasar build ?

Comment: Try [this](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/handling-process-env/#using-dotenv).

Comment: also, your closing parenthesis and the curly brace seems wrongly placed. It should be `})` not `)}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1-) Create your relevant environment variables files in the home directory. Recommended filenames:

**.env.development / .env.production**

2-) In **quasar.conf.js** use **dotenv** library (if not installed: **npm install dotenv --save**):

```
const env = require('dotenv').config({ path: `.env.${process.env.ENV_FILE.toLowerCase()}` }).parsed
```

then put vars to quasar environment variables:

```
build: {
       env: {
         ...env
       }
}
```

3-) Then run build command based on the environment variable file you want:

```
ENV_FILE=development quasar build
```

**NOTE**: Using an environment variable on the command line is not the same on all operating systems.

If you are using Windows:

```
$env:ENV_FILE="development"; quasar build
```

Comment: "build:stg": "cross-env ENV_FILE=stg quasar build" . I installed the package cross-env and that solved the issue for my on Windows. Thanks to all the users that reply